# UILabel возвращает nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! Cell2

var user: User


if shouldShowTheResult
{
    user = self.filtered[indexPath.row]

}
else
{

    user = MessageController.users[indexPath.row]
    print(user.name)
}

cell.nameLabel.text = user.name <<-- Здесь возвращает nil


return cell
}
```

Comment: Так UILabel или user все же nil возвращает?

Comment: Не уточнил, UILabel возвращает nil

Comment: так что имеено в той строке nil? cell или только label?

Comment: nameLabel = (UILabel!)nil - это в debug area

Comment: а cell не nil??